# Rxjs in Ngrx - call action after filter/end of side effect

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I'm using Angular 7 with the NGRX store. I have an effect, which will retrieve me some data if it doesn't exist in the store. I'm using the `filter` operator, but I always need to call an action, whether the data exists or not, at the end of the side effect. Here is my side effect (simplified):

```
getChartData$ = this.actions$
    .pipe(
        ofType(GET_CHART_DATA),
        withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(x => x.store))),
        filter(((obj: [any, store]) => {
            return this.dataExistsInStore()
        })),
        map(obj => obj[0]),
        mergeMap((action) => this.chartService.getChartData((action as any).payload)
            .pipe(
                map((chartData: ChartData) =>
                    ({ type: GET_CHART_DATA_SUCCESS, payload: { tagId: (action as any).payload, chartData: chartData } })
                ),
                catchError(() => of({ type: GET_CHART_DATA_FAILED }))
            ))
    );

dataExistsInStore(): boolean
{
    return x;
}
```

How can I call an action even after the filter, e.g. an action of type `GET_CHART_DATA_COMPLETE`. I need to do this so I can hide the loading indicator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you would like to :

- invoke `getChartData` only if data is not existing in store
- dispatch an `GET_CHART_DATA_COMPLETE` action in all the case

If that is true. You could consider this approach: (sorry, may have typos)

```
getChartData$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(GET_CHART_DATA),
  withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(isDataExistingInStore))),
  mergeMap(([action, isDataExistingInStore]: [Action, boolean]) => {
    if (!isDataExistingInStore) {
      return this.chartService.getChartData(action.payload).pipe(
        map((chartData: ChartData) =>
                ({ type: GET_CHART_DATA_SUCCESS, payload: { tagId: (action as any).payload, chartData: chartData } })
            ),
        catchError(() => of({ type: GET_CHART_DATA_FAILED }))
      )
    } else {
      return of({ type: GET_CHART_DATA_COMPLETE })    
    };
  )
)
```

Here I'm considering, you have a `selector` : `isDataExistingInStore`, which return a boolean.

**Bonus**: May I suggest you to use `ngrx` best practice to create actions:

```
new GetChartDataSuccess(payload)
```

or even better with action creators in `version 8` :

```
myActions.getChartDataSuccess({ tagId: .... });
```